# ERROR [+2640] TreeBuildCommand: TB commands must be in sequence

Tags: cygwin, speech-recognition, htk

I have added some words like name of fruits in the sample tutorial provided in the voxforge julius tutorial. I think the grammar and voca file are correct and i am stuck at this last step at this last error.

I have checked my monophones0 file i havent made any changes in that i just copied it as it is in the tutorial made the tree with the perl command. I dont know why i have this error now.

TB 350.00 ST_a_2_ {}
 Tree based clustering
  ERROR [+2640]  TreeBuildCommand: TB commands must be in sequence

need help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify perl script in order to work with your phoneset. The resulting tree.hed should not have lines like this

```
TB 350.00 ST_a_2_ {}
```

Instead, lines should look like

```
TB 350 "ST_jh_2_" {("jh","*-jh+*","jh+*","*-jh").state[2]}
```

Comment: This is my mkclscript.prl what changes do you want me to do... cause i changed it already by adding another chop to it... and the lines i get in tree.hhed are like

TB 350 "ST_a_2_" {("a","*-a+*","a+*","*-a").state[2]}
TB 350 "ST__2_" {("","*-+*","+*","*-").state[2]}
TB 350 "ST_a_2_" {("a","*-a+*","a+*","*-a").state[2]}
TB 350 "ST__2_" {("","*-+*","+*","*-").state[2]}

Comment: I wana show you my perl script and the lines i get from the tree what  you want me to edit in that. i posted a new question linking this one and it is closed by someone  now

Comment: New question was a bad idea. However, this thing ST__2 appears in your tree.hed because you have an empty line in your monophones file and it's not filtered by a perl script. Try to remove empty lines or add the filter for empty lines in the perl script and it should be fine.

Comment: yeah now i know it was a bad idea. I trid removing spaces i tried to re do everything from step1 but still i got the same error. I have no idea what to do next may be h_vite log file can help. If it can i dont know how should i check and match it with the example given but i have added new words to the grammer and voca file. any suggestions please.

Comment: I tried it manyy times there arent any empty spaces in monophones0 monophones1 file. please help!!

Comment: Empty lines, not empty spaces. You can provide the files you are using (pack them into archive, upload to a file sharing resource and give here a link) to get more definite advice.

Comment: I have added my manuals and tree.hed file included in it please have a look at it. I will wait for your advice.


https://fts.capgemini.com/pubpwd/37586894007840/manual.zip link valid until 2012-07-26 13:00 UTC (public access with local password)

Additional credentials, to enter in specific popup box when prompted for authentication:
Username: xsvkrzmou
Password: UVqrgt4cTs

Comment: I see your screwed this file altogether. Try to start the process from the beginning of the tutorial chapter. You need to create the beginning of the file again. Then you need to run the perl script mkclscript.prl only once. Try to understand what each command does before you run it.

Comment: I did everything again from step one and now i am stuck at the same step but with a different error. I tried to read the documents and find whats the sltion but i cannot find any. When i run

HHEd -A -D -T 1 -H hmm12/macros -H hmm12/hmmdefs -M hmm13 tree.hed triphones1


 ERROR [+7036]  NewMacro: macro or model name ST_s_2_1 already exists

I am attaching link again for my manual

https://fts.capgemini.com/pubpwd/8051466057582/manual.zip
For authentication:
Username: nigafghzy
Password: FsQfHQr3j7

I dont want to do anything till you reply I need to do it please help asap. Thank you!

Comment: Again, your tree.hed is not correct. It looks like you were using a wrong file as an input for the perl script mkclscript.pl. You need to use the file monophones0. You need to revert changes to tree.hed you made before next attempt.

Comment: Hi,I did the same steps again and end up with the same error i did made changes to my tree file before the attempt.I read mkclscript.prl and it uses monophones. should i change "monophones" to "monophones0". I have no idea how to troubleshoot as i dont know perl but i am trying hard to get it as it is the last step. please give any suggestion if possible. thank you so much in advance.

Comment: this are the two lines i think if it has a problem cause they decide the file to be read while making chnages to the tree i think.



if ( $#ARGV != 2 ) {
   die "usage: mkclscript.prl command threshold monophone_list\n";
}

$command = $ARGV[0];
$threshold = $ARGV[1];

$hmmlist=$ARGV[2];
if (! -f $hmmlist) {
   die "mkclscript: monophone HMM list $hmmlist not found\n";

Answer (score 0):

At first accept my apologies if I am wrong. 
In the tree.hed file there are three sections TR0, TR2, TR1.

AT the TR2 section the last line was:

> TB 350 "ST_sil_4_" {("sil","*-sil+*","sil+*","*-sil").state[4]}

Then TR1 section starts where it was supposed to add only the following additional lines:

> TR 1
>
> AU "./fulllist"
>
> CO "./tiedlist"
>
> ST "./trees"

But in my case mkclscript.jl script added some lines in between the two portions I mentioned above. So I removed those portion and it worked fine for me. I believe the problem is with the script. Hope it helps.